# Does SSL connection provide any unique user identifier?

Tags: php, ssl, nginx

Because of the hardware limitations (at the network level), we are not able to use client IP to uniquely identify devices. However, all of the communication is done through HTTPS.

Does SSL session provide any unique user identifier?

Comment: The problem with this question is that every time the SSL session is re-established (say, for a subsequent request) the "identifier" would be different. So if you want a per-connection identifier then you can use IP _and_ port to uniquely identify a remote connection; or if you want a per-session (which might involve multiple connects and disconnects) then you are limited to cookies or some other tag passed via the `GET` or `POST` requests.

Comment: Any user identifier has to be passed as part of the request, which isn't different from regular HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSL *can* provide client certificates for authentication if you've generated certificates and distributed them to all clients in advance, however there is no built in unique user identifier in the protocol itself.

The easy way to do it is to let the client log in using HTTP authentication over the SSL channel once it's up.